# REGEDIT. Создание дополнительной опции "Открыть в %программа%" для конкретного расширения

Tags: windows, regedit

Необходимо добавить опцию "открыть в %моя программа%" в контекстное меню для avi файлов не заменяя при этом программу по умолчанию.

[image: Должно выглядеть это примерно так]

По различным мануалам были добавлены ключи:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.avi\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.avi\shell\my_application]
@="my app title"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\icon_64.ico"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.avi\shell\my_application\command]
@="\"C:\\User\\\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\open.bat\" \"%1\""
```

и

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application\shell\Open]
"FriendlyAppName"="my app title"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application\shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\open.bat\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application\SupportedTypes]
".avi"=""
```

Однако все это не дало нужного эффекта. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оставлю решение и закрою вопрос:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avi\Shell\my_application]
@="my app title"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\icon_64.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avi\Shell\my_application\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\open.bat\" \"%1\""
```

p.s. Спасибо w32sh.